# What is the chemical symbol for Mu-mesic atoms?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, notation

Is there a convention for chemical symbols of mu-mesic atoms, at least for ones bound to light atomic nuclei?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an official convention for a positive muon being a nucleus, that a positive muon with one electron is muonium ($\mathrm{Mu}$) and a positive muon with two electrons is muonide ($\mathrm{Mu^-}$). See [Names for Muonic and Hydrogen Atoms and Their Ions](http://www.iupac.org/publications/pac/2001/pdf/7302x0377.pdf).

For a negative muon replacing an electron in helium, I see both $\mathrm{He\mu}$ and $\mathrm{^{4.1}H}$ in the same paper: [Kinetic Isotope Effects for the Reactions of Muonic Helium and Muonium with $\mathrm{H_2}$](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/331/6016/448.short).